# Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe not recognised

Tags: .net, containers, docker-container

C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe not recognised as internal or external command. I am getting this error when I containerize the web service(.asmx, .Net 3.5) using docker compose on visual studio.

I am not able to find appcmd.exe in the above mentioned location also.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Why are you using pipe instead of slash ? (`||` instead of ``\\`` after C:)

Comment: Typo it is, thanks.